# Accessing Tomcat 8 JNDI from Standalone JVM

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

I have a legacy webapp recently converted to running on a Tomcat 8 server that calls a java command (Runtime.getRuntime().exec) in the contextInitialized method.  This java program then needs to lookup and use the resources (database info) that are set up in the Tomcat context.xml file.  It doesn't appear that Tomcat exposes these resources like Websphere.

So what is my best route to access these resources in this separate JVM?  Maybe there is a context friendly way to spin off the java process?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you can't. The JNDI context is available as read-only from within the webapp.

Comment: So I think my options here are to either accept that I have to run the program within context of my webapp in the same JVM or deploy it in it's own Tomcat server with it's own context.